# Stocks management for warehouse

Tags: mysql, inventory-management

I am trying to create a stock management system for a warehouse which has various items. I'm currently stuck with thinking how my tables should look like. I am designing it based on the delivery receipts my boss handed to me. Here's what some the delivery receipts contain:

```
Delivery receipt# :1
Quantity: 60 pcs 
Item description : 
    T SHIRTS with logo
        small : 10 pcs
        xsmall : 20 pcs
        large : 30 pcs

------------------

Delivery receipt#: 2
Quantity :  40 pcs 
Item description :   
    Tumblers with straw
        2 BOXES * 20 pcs (this is 20pc/per box)

------------------

Delivery receipt#: 2
Quantity :  100 pcs 
Item description :   
    Marketing brochures
        10 bundles * 10 pcs (10 pcs per bundle)
```

I'm planning to make those data below the item description generic. But I dont have a proper term for it.

Can you suggest how my items table will look like?

Thanks!

Comment: Do these deliveries have a few item type or only one ?

Comment: What do you mean by item type, sorry? Their items can range from tents, tshirts, bags, brochures, balloons, pens and so on.

Comment: What I think of having is a one-to-many relationship between the main item (found in the first line of item description) and those lines that come after it. I can't think of the proper term for it :)

Comment: I mean when i give an order, could it include brochures and T-Shirts at the same time ?

Comment: I haven't seen a delivery receipt with multiple item types, although that's a possibility but lets just assume we have 1 item type per delivery

Comment: i will try to draw something wait a sec.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Often, the best approach is to pull out the nouns from your description.

- Delivery receipt
- Item Description

Now obviously, `Receipt` will be a table. So what does it contain?

- Quantity
- Item

But this means you can only have one item per purchase, which isn't reasonable, so we'll port this to a new table, `ReceiptItems`. With this, you use the primary key of the `receipt number`, and the primary key of what will become out `item` table.

**Receipt Items**

*ReceiptID* (Primary Key and Foreign Key)

*ItemID* (Primary Key and Foreign Key)

*Quantity*

**Items**

*ItemID* (Primary Key)

*Item Description*

*Item Price*

*Item Type*

**Receipt**

*ReceiptID* (Primary Key)

*Buyer* (Just another optional one)

Comment: in Items table u can add ItemType which is related another one like : **ItemTypes**
ItemID
ItemTypeID

**ItemTypeList**
ItemTypeID
ItemTypeName -> (you can stor 'small','large' etc here)

Comment: This is nice, but how can I record this breakdown ?
Item description :   T SHIRTS with logo
  small : 10 pcs
  xsmall : 20 pcs
  large : 30 pcs

same goes with flyers,banners, bags,etc..

Comment: @SercanOzdemir I'm not sure if another table for something like that is completely necessary. I'm not sure what you mean by "this breakdown"?

Comment: @ChrisCooney what I mean't by breakdown are those lines just below the first line of item description. As you can see, the Quantity is the total of those lines. I really lack the proper term for those (attributes, properties,sizes?)

Comment: Each item should have it's own primary key. Whether it is a small or a large T shirt, it should be uniquely identifiable.. Quantity can be worked out on the fly by summing each item ID's cost together.